# How to group mounted devices under Nautilus icon in the launcher?

Tags: nautilus, launcher

I am using three physical discs in my computer, first mounted in */*, second in */home/me/XMem* and the third one in */media/me/stor*.
In Ubuntu 14.04, opening any folder in any of the discs opened Nautilus under the nautilus icon. However, in Ubuntu 16.04, folders in all discs apart from the first one open in its own icon of the mounted disc.

[image]

How can I group it back to the Nautilus icon?

Answer (score 0):

This is sorted out in this solution. It is not grouping but it is behaving like in 14.04. [How to stop partition icons in Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811867/how-to-stop-partition-icons-in-unity-launcher)

Comment: "If the device is opened in any nautilus window, it will still show up in the launcher. The icon will however not be locked to the launcher, and disappear."
It seems your proposed solution won't solve this problem, which lies in having an icon for every partition.